# AWS IOT - What is the best way to establish device ownership and prevent unauthorized access

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

In AWS IOT I don't see any explanation online describing the best way to ensure a device publishing a topic with sensitive data can only be accessed by the device's owner.

For example Bob logs into his smartphone app and authenticates using Cognito. There is already a policy on the identity pool auth role allowing access to AWS IOT and an administrative lambda has called AttachPrincipalPolicy during signup and gave Bob access to AWS IOT.

Bob owns a device called "thermostat" with an x509 cert installed on it that is used to authenticate with AWS IOT. It is publishing topics such as /thermostat/123/temperature/75 (serial #:123, temperature: 75) and Bob on his smartphone is subscribing to the same topic (/thermostat/123/temperature/*)

How do we prevent another user, Jill, who has gone through the same setup for her thermostat, which gives her access to AWS IOT, from subscribing to /thermostat/123/temperature/* and reading Bob's private data?

I'm guessing it has to do with the serial number but in that case how do you associate Bob's identity ID with the device's serial number? What is the best way to associate the user and device when each is using a completely different authentication mechanism (Cognito and X509)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in that case how do you associate Bob's identity ID with the device's serial number?

[ThingAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_ThingAttribute.html) can store simple device-owner relations. Add an `ownerID` attribute to your device Things. Or use an external store for more complex scenarios.

AWS suggests in its [MQTT Topic Design doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/designing-mqtt-topics-aws-iot-core/mqtt-design-best-practices.html) to "Include any relevant routing information in the MQTT topic".  Topic patterns such as `jill/thermostat/123/temperature/*` might be useful if you have single, stable owners.  A [thing policy variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-policy-variables.html) `{iot:Connection.Thing.Attributes[ownerID]}`in the [IoT Core Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html) can make these dynamic.

> Cognito auth: How do we prevent another user, Jill ... reading Bob's private data?

When Jill authenticates to IoT Core with Amazon Cognito identities, your client code or a lambda can generate the user-specific IoT Core Policy to attach to Jill's user identity [as part of the auth flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cog-iot-policies.html).  The policy will be written to allow Jill access only to her devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a best practice on using a key that the device and the user can share? For Cognito the topic might be {IdentityId}/thermostat.... and for the device it might be {CertKey}/thermostat and so there is no connection between the device and user. Do you provision the device with the Cognito Identity ID during registration so it can send on Cognito ID instead of CertKey? Is there a better method?

Comment: also the attachpolicy, as far as I understand, gives the user access to AWS IoT but how can I prevent access to other people's devices?

Comment: Glad to help.   No one-size-fits-all "best" for the first questions, really.  It depends on your use case and the trade-offs you want to make.  Loose coupling is a good idea, but harder to implement.   You could achieve this by [republishing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-repub-rule.html) incoming device messages to owner topics using a rule which  triggers a lambda.   Having said that, my advice is to start simple and add complexity as you need it.

Comment: Re: policy.   The link in the answer has some code examples, but it's up to you to code the device lookup logic in the lambda such that the IoT core policy only has Jill's devices as `resources`.  Your lambda could make a `iot.listThings` api call when Jill logs in, filtering on Jill's id as the `attributeName:"ownerID"` `attributeValue:<jill's id>`, and returning an IoT Core Policy based on that device list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @fedonev