# How to get user's spesific "Things" from AWS IoT service and not all the Things in the system

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I develop an **android** app and I want to get only **Things** that related to spesific logged-in user
currently I get all the Things in the system and I want to avoid the retrieve all the Things from AWS.

```
val awsIotClient = AWSIotClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance())
awsIotClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2))
val userListThings = awsIotClient.listThings(ListThingsRequest())
```

this is the code i use to get all the **Things**, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You first need a way to associate a user with her devices.  A simple option is to add an `owner` [Thing Attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-thing-management.html).  Attributes are key-value pairs we can set on Things.

Once we define the Thing owners, we can filter Things by owner with the optional `attributeName` and `attributeValue` inputs to [listThings](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/services/iot/AWSIot.html#listThings-com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.ListThingsRequest-):

```py
# python, but the android API has the same method signature
iot.list_things(attributeName="owner", attributeValue="me")
```

```json
{'things': [{'thingName': 'temp1',
   'thingArn': 'arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:thing/temp1',
   'attributes': {'owner': 'me'},
   'version': 1}]}
```

Note that this approach is just filtering the Things. It does not restrict access.

Comment: I aware of this option but it will lead to security issues if each app can get all the devices right? there is probably a more correct way to do this ...

Comment: Right. The question does not mention an access control requirement or say what you already tried, only "avoid the retrieve of all Things".  The answer's last sentence warns it does not address authorisation.  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254746/aws-iot-what-is-the-best-way-to-establish-device-ownership-and-prevent-unautho) for an approach that does.

Comment: Thank you for your response , base on what to wrote in "this related question" link I understand that the lambda will create and attach the IoT policy for the user that is logged in right after the lambda will filter all the devices base on the "attributeName"
I have 2 questions:
1. Is it the only way to do it securely(using lambda)? can the mobile SDK do that instead?
2. I new to the concept of server-less functions can you refer me to a link that describe how to create lambda that create "IoT Policy" in AWS

Comment: Glad to help.  (1) With AWS, there is never only one way to do anything... but if security is important, you should avoid creating permissions with the mobile SDK.  Never trust the client.  (2) [this aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cog-iot-policies.html) has lambda IoT policy logic examples.  The lambda's job is to look up the user's devices and return the device-specific policies.  Creating a lambda [is easy](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/run-serverless-code/), with lots of online help available.